# All lug nuts come off without any warning and studs backed off

Tags: wheels, jeep, wrangler, stud

I was replacing the wheels on my 2011 jeep wrangler sahara,torqued to 95 lb/ft and when i went to go test drive it nothing felt off until i was on the highway and before i even got to 80 km/h my wheel came off and I didn’t see any lugnuts around me. Idk when they came off or why i felt nothing until my car folded on its self but when i got it towed back to my garage the driver had a bit of trouble getting it off his flat bed because the wheel was binding on broken studs, i removed all my wheels because i was paranoid but they were still all tight. But when i looked at the damage I noticed that 1 stud was bent and broken: half was still in the rotor but the other half backed off and fell behind my hub and between the rotor destroy the abs sensor, and another stud had also completely backed off and was binding on the hub bolts. And the rest of the studs were bent and had started backing off, and the wheel is done it looks like i bashed the face thats on the hub with a hammer. But im just wondering if anybody has any idea what could’ve happened all the rest of the wheels were still tight and i had no warning, it was really smooth till it wasn’t. Has this happened to anyone? Ive been starting to second guess if I genuinely torqued them or if i just hit them with the gun with a 65 lb/ft torque stick and then got distracted and never torqued them.

Comment: Some people also actually put anti-seize and other lubricants on the wheel studs so they come off more easily when servicing. Do not do that. Stories like this is why. I'm not saying you did this, but it might be.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with your thought that you didn’t torque them properly.

I would say that the bent one was the last one to hold onto the wheel while the others were getting “hammered” in by the rear face of the wheel just before it came off.